# How do I adjust the labels for my pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, legend, pie-chart

I am creating a pie chart to show the percentages of property types available in a dataset in the column `["PTypes"]`. I used the code below

```
    `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    # Pie chart
df['PType'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%', pctdistance=1, labeldistance=1.3, fontsize=12, figsize=(8,6))

   plt.pie(sizes, colors = colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90, pctdistance=0.85, explode = explode)
    #draw circle
    centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.70,fc='white')
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
    # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle
    ax.axis('equal')  
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()`
```

This is the result it produced.

[image]

Yeah I know it looks a bit odd. I need to adjust the labels, get rid of the red background at the top and introduce a legend.

How can I do that?

Comment: @JohanC I have tried to adjust the question and the code, it produced the same result though without the labels and sizes. I guess its the character of the data. I just need to adjust it now.

I want to use pie chart to show the the combination of properties available in a data in the column [PTypes]. Ignore the labels and sizes. I have removed them from the code, bu the result is the same.

Comment: To draw a donut chart: https://python-graph-gallery.com/161-custom-matplotlib-donut-plot/  Add the "explode" part if desired.

Comment: Please, please, don't remove data. Now it is even harder to understand. Please add some data that shows what you need. Do you need one or two "donut" type of charts? With or without the parts being "exploded"? Now you are drawing two pie charts. The strange red parts are from the first pie chart, which also makes the labels weird. If you remove `df['PType'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', ...` that first pie chart will also be removed.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59153347/matplotlib-pie-donut-chart-annotation-text-size) also has information about playing around with the text labels.